# Power BI calculation issue. Minusing yesterday's value from today's value results in 17908 throughout the table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I trying to work with COVID data and find the day on day increase of cases. Essentially, take today's value and minus yesterday's value to get the increase figure. My data also starts on April 10th so if the data is this, I will return a 0.

Given the below formula, the 0 is correctly returned for April 10th but all other values return 17908. All column types are 'Whole number'. Can anybody give me some information on this? Apologies if this is an obvious issue, I am used to working with Python and R and have been thrust into Power BI.

My data is very simple. It just continues like this:

ID  Date          No of cases

1)           10 April    3

1)   11 April   6

1)   12 April   15

```
Diff_Daily =
VAR blankValue = 0
VAR difference =
    SUM ( Table[No of cases] )
        - CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[No of cases] ), PREVIOUSDAY ( Table[Date] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( Table[Date].[Date] = DATE ( 2020, 04, 10 ), blankValue, difference )
```

Comment: is 17908 the total of the whole table? have you tried to spit this into different measures? (Cases, Cases Prev Day, Delta). Can you provide a bunch of sample data?

Comment: You are exactly correct! It is the total. So it appears I am summing the column, and putting the result as every value in my new column.I will edit my question with a sample of the data.

Comment: I'm not sure about what's wrong in your formula (except the IF condition at the end), to me it works fine, maybe is something linked to the data types, I will post an answer with some formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve that I made the following measures. I made more than one just because to me it usually makes more sense (you can re-use them in a KPI or other charts) but you can merge them together if you don't need them all.

```
Cases = SUM(MyTable[No Of Cases])

Cases (prev Day) = 
CALCULATE(
    [Cases]
    ,PREVIOUSDAY(MyTable[Date])
)

Daily Delta = 
IF(ISBLANK([Cases (prev Day)])
    ,0
    ,[Cases] - [Cases (prev Day)]
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

About your formula, It looks nice to me, I suggest you check the data type of your columns, especially the date one. other than that the only error I see is the use of a field inside the `IF` statement, you may want to use `ISBLANK([MyMeasure])` (at least in this case)

Comment: Thanks for that @giovanni Luisotto. 

I'm new to PowerBI, I'm used to Python, R, SQL etc. Does `CALCULATE([Cases]` need an expression? I can't seem to call [cases]. It requires something like SUM for example?

Comment: [Cases] is a measure (an expression if you want), which is getting called in another measure [Cases (prev Day)]. You will find its formula in the answer

Comment: Gotcha, I missed some brackets! Thanks.